# Modified Hangman game, optimal algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The computer now randomly selects one of these words and a program should guess the word with as few attempts as possible.

The computer gives it the following hints for this after a tip

1. begins with
2. ends with
3. contains
4. does not include

Let's take the word house as an example: If we guess "h" then we get as an answer the searched word begins with "h". If we guess "ous" we get the answer that the searched word contains  "ous" usw. If we guess "house" then we get as an answer that we found the correct word.

Is there an optimal strategy for this Problem? The naive approach would be simply to try every word. Of course, that's very bad. A better approach, I think. As first tip choose the most common letter etc. But I think you can do it a lot more efficiently

Comment: how do we know when we win?

Comment: @juvian We get a message from the computer wich says, that we guess the right word.

Comment: What if a letter satisfies all of the first three conditions? Like baobab?

Comment: I started reading the question, and I felt like I had missed a few sentences: *"the computer now randomly selects"* - the 'now' implies something else has already happened - did something happen before that? *"one of these words"* - which words? Perhaps this was someone working on the same challenge? https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/really-need-advice-java-program-assignment-guessing-game-user-imports-file-list-words-scan-q6338023

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an optimal strategy.  However, that strategy depends on solving the game tree for the given word list.  The word list is finite; you have a finite set of choices at every node; each guess can be configured to guarantee that the result *adds* a non-trivial quantity of information, thus moving you significantly closer to the solution.  Ergo, the game tree is finite.

Build the game tree for the given lexicon (word list).  If you want the guaranteed *optimal* attack, you'll need to solve the game tree, involving **minimax** and **pruning**.  If you want to find a *very good* attack in less time, then draw from the ML (machine learning) area of **decision trees**.

Is that enough to move you in the direction of a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Now I have some things I can research.  But can there be a solution that requires asymptotically less than log(n) attempts ( if n is the number of possible words )?

Comment: @ueial Consider you make a query, your answer will provide information with which you can discard some entries. You would need to discard at least half on each query to make a log(n) solution, don´t think that is possible. Note that you can make a simple strategy that solves any word in at most 26 + k*(l-2) queries with k being the amount of different characters and l the length of the word.

Comment: @ueial: No, you can't do better than **O(log(n))**.  In fact, a carefully constructed word list will leave you with **O(n)**.  A word list that's constructed to be optimal for *you* will be **O(log8(n))**, since you can extract 8 classifications (3 binary decisions) from each guess.